# comparing two lists in linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists: orders and items and I need to compare them by their name AND then look if order list have bool set to false and if it satysfy the condition it copies its string message and then adds to new list and I just have no freaking idea even how to compare lists, so any help will be appreciated
Function:

```
 private static void FailedItemsList(List<Item> failed, List<Order> orders, List<Item> items)
{
    foreach(var order in orders)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            if(order.Equals(item))
            {
                if(order.Fulfilled == false)
                {
                    item.FailMessage = order.FailMessage;
                    failed.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What's the needed output?

Comment: I forgot to say that Equals compares order.Name to item.Name, so in linq i need that it would compare thei names and if it matches then check if order.Fulfilled == false and if it is then item should copy FailMessage and add that item to new list, I know its a big mess but thats the thing i was asked :(

Comment: Are you sure that your code works, Order is a different class than Item but you are using order.Equals(item)?

Comment: Yeah it works, because It was public class Order : IEquatable<Item> and had Equals method, who compared and your GetFailedItems method worked just fine, tanks

Answer (score 2):

In general i would return this "fail-list" from the method instead of passing it to it. You could use LINQ to simplify this task:

```
static List<Item> GetFailedItems(List<Order> orders, List<Item> items)
{
    var failed = from order in orders
                 where !order.Fulfilled
                 join item in items on order.Name equals item.Name
                 select new { order, item};

    List<Item> failedItems = new List<Item>();
    foreach (var x in failed)
    {
        x.item.FailMessage = x.order.FailMessage;
        failedItems.Add(x.item);
    }

    return failedItems;
}
```

Since `Item` and `Order` are different classes i have removed the `Equals` check and replaced it with a join on the `Name` property as desired. Since LINQ should not cause side effects i haven't modifed the `Item.FailMessage` property in the query but in the `foreach`-loop. Due to LINQ's deferred execution(the query gets executed at the `foreach`) this is not less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = from x in orders
        where x.Fulfilled == false
        join item in items on order.Name equals item.Name
        select x.FailMessage;

foreach (int i in v)
    failed.Add(i);
```